# How can object key be of Symbol.iterator type

Tags: javascript

I know that ES5 object keys are of String type. If I specify anything else for object key, for example it will be converted to string:

```
var o = {}
var f = function() {}
// `toString` method is called on f
o[f]= 3
```

[In this](http://www.2ality.com/2015/02/es6-iteration.html) article I see that `Symbol.iterator` is used as a key:

```
let iterable = {
    [Symbol.iterator]() {
        let step = 0;
        let iterator = {
            next() {
                if (step <= 2) {
                    step++;
                }
                switch (step) {
                    case 1:
                        return { value: 'hello', done: false };
                    case 2:
                        return { value: 'world', done: false };
                    default:
                        return { value: undefined, done: true };
                }
            }
        };
        return iterator;
    }
};
```

So is `Symbol.iterator` coerced into a string?

Comment: you've forgotten to add reference article -))

Comment: thanks, added the link

Comment: You're correct about ES5 object keys, but if you're using ES2015 it's simply not ES5 anymore. Symbols are also object properties. They don't coerce into string. Standard link: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-symbol-value

Comment: @Andrey, thanks, what are the valid types for ES6 object keys now?

Comment: @Maximus, 4.3.30: property   -  

part of an object that associates a key (either a String value or a Symbol value) and a value

Comment: @Andrey, got it, thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: `Symbol.iterator` does not coerce into string.

> [Symbol.iterator] A zero arguments function that returns an object,
>   conforming to the iterator protocol.
>
> "Symbol.iterator" is a method that returns the default Iterator for an
>   object. Called by the semantics of the for-of statement.

Look at this example:

```
var iterator = 'hi'[Symbol.iterator]();
iterator + "";                               // "[object String Iterator]"

iterator.next();                             // { value: "h", done: false }
iterator.next();                             // { value: "i", done: false }
iterator.next();
typeof Symbol.iterator;      // "symbol"
Symbol.iterator.toString();  // "Symbol(Symbol.iterator)"
```

---

Also a `Symbol` does not coerce into a string.

> To create a new primitive symbol, you write Symbol() with an optional
>   string as its description:
>
> ```
> var sym1 = Symbol();
> var sym2 = Symbol("foo");
> var sym3 = Symbol("foo");
> ```
>
> The above code creates three new symbols. Note that Symbol("foo") does
>   not coerce the string "foo" into a symbol. It creates a new symbol
>   each time: [Resouce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol)

Comment: Thanks, but `Symbol.iterator` is used as an object key, not `Symbol()`

Comment: @Maximus I made an edit to my answer, I hope it helps :)

Comment: thanks, so basically `Symbol.iterator` is a some kind of constant, correct? as `Symbol.iterator===Symbol.iterator; // true`

Comment: `Symbol.iterator` property has the attributes
 { [[Writable]]: false, [[Enumerable]]: false, [[Configurable]]: false

Comment: sorry, don't understand why you mentioned properties, can you clarify?

Comment: @Maximus no problems, Symbol.iterator is a property of  primitive type Symbols in ECMAScript 6

Comment: Useful articles if you are interested to know more: http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_symbols.html and https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/31e1d4ff600d88cc2ce243903ab8a3a9d15cce15/es6%20%26%20beyond/ch3.md